# Chef installation error - VDD

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, virtualbox, chef-solo, vagrant-windows

I am absolutely new to VDD. My PC is running Windows 10.
I installed VirtualBox, Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack and finally tried installing Vagrant. But received a series of errors when installing Vagrant.

I downloaded all installation files from [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2008792).

> ==> default: ================================================================================
>   ==> default: Error executing action `run` on resource 'bash[install-drush-master]'
>   ==> default: ================================================================================
>   ==> default:
>   ==> default:
>   ==> default: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
>   ==> default: ------------------------------------
>   ==> default: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '2'
>   ==> default: ---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160317-7824-17c8y7m" ----
>   ==> default: STDOUT:
>   ==> default: STDERR: You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performan
>   ce. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
>   ==> default: Loading composer repositories with package information
>   ==> default: Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
>   ==> default: Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be gett
>   ing outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
>   ==> default: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>   ==> default:
>   ==> default:   Problem 1
>   ==> default:     - Installation request for symfony/console v3.0.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.0.3].
>   ==> default:     - symfony/console v3.0.3 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.45) does not satisfy th
>   at requirement.
>   ==> default:   Problem 2
>   ==> default:     - Installation request for symfony/filesystem v3.0.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/filesystem[v3.0
>   .3].
>   ==> default:     - symfony/filesystem v3.0.3 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.45) does not satisfy
>    that requirement.
>   ==> default:   Problem 3
>   ==> default:     - Installation request for symfony/var-dumper v3.0.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v3.0
>   .3].
>   ==> default:     - symfony/var-dumper v3.0.3 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.45) does not satisfy
>    that requirement.
>   ==> default:   Problem 4
>   ==> default:     - Installation request for symfony/yaml v3.0.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/yaml[v3.0.3].
>   ==> default:     - symfony/yaml v3.0.3 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.45) does not satisfy that 
>   requirement.
>   ==> default:   Problem 5
>   ==> default:     - symfony/console v3.0.3 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.45) does not satisfy th
>   at requirement.
>   ==> default:     - psy/psysh v0.7.2 requires symfony/console ~2.3.10|^2.4.2|~3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/cons
>   ole[v3.0.3].
>   ==> default:     - Installation request for psy/psysh v0.7.2 -> satisfiable by psy/psysh[v0.7.2].
>   ==> default: ---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160317-7824-17c8y7m" ----
>   ==> default: Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160317-7824-17c8y7m" returned 2
>
> ==> default: [2016-03-17T21:50:09+00:00] ERROR: bash[install-drush-master] (vdd::drush line 16) had an error: M
>   ixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '2'
>   ==> default: ---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160317-7824-17c8y7m" ----
>   ==> default: STDOUT:
>   ==> default: STDERR: You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performan
>   ce. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
>   ==> default: Loading composer repositories with package information
>   ==> default: Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
>   ==> default: Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be gett
>   ing outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
>   ==> default: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>   ==> default:
>   ==> default:   Problem 1
>   ==> default:     - Installation request for symfony/console v3.0.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.0.3].
>   ==> default:     - symfony/console v3.0.3 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.45) does not satisfy th
>   at requirement.
>   ==> default:   Problem 2
>   ==> default:     - Installation request for symfony/filesystem v3.0.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/filesystem[v3.0
>   .3].
>   ==> default:     - symfony/filesystem v3.0.3 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.45) does not satisfy
>    that requirement.
>   ==> default:   Problem 3
>   ==> default:     - Installation request for symfony/var-dumper v3.0.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v3.0
>   .3].
>   ==> default:     - symfony/var-dumper v3.0.3 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.45) does not satisfy
>    that requirement.
>   ==> default:   Problem 4
>   ==> default:     - Installation request for symfony/yaml v3.0.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/yaml[v3.0.3].
>   ==> default:     - symfony/yaml v3.0.3 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.45) does not satisfy that 
>   requirement.
>   ==> default:   Problem 5
>   ==> default:     - symfony/console v3.0.3 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.45) does not satisfy th
>   at requirement.
>   ==> default:     - psy/psysh v0.7.2 requires symfony/console ~2.3.10|^2.4.2|~3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/cons
>   ole[v3.0.3].
>   ==> default:     - Installation request for psy/psysh v0.7.2 -> satisfiable by psy/psysh[v0.7.2].
>   ==> default: ---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160317-7824-17c8y7m" ----
>   ==> default: Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160317-7824-17c8y7m" returned 2
>   ==> default: [2016-03-17T21:50:09+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited u
>   nsuccessfully (exit code 1)
>   Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
>   output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.

Sorry for pasting such a long error message, but I have absolutely no idea what to do next.

Please help.

Comment: It seems the composer.json file used require using PHP 5.5.9 but the rest of the cookbooks install php 5.4.45. This probably need an update somewhere but I assume it's better to fill an issue on Drupal side than a question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

As was indicated by **Tensibai**'s comment, there appears to be an issue with the version of PHP on the Ubuntu box (12.04) installed as part of that tutorial. Specifically, the version of PHP is insufficient to complete the install.

You will either need to manually change the provision script to install a newer version of PHP and reprovision (`vagrant up --provision`), or ssh into the box (`vagrant ssh`) and install PHP manually.

The below code will add a PPA (a place Ubuntu looks for software) which has a newer version of PHP5 which will run on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php5
```

I believe that will get you to at least PHP 5.5.9 on Ubuntu 12.04.

If you need more help, please post a comment.